# Stop automatic addition of fields to page layouts

Tags: salesforce

I want to know if there is a way to stop being prompted to automatically add new custom fields to page layouts?  I have a few developers that "forget" to uncheck that box and then the fields are mobilized to all the layouts.  This is not ideal and would love to disable this feature.  If this is not the correct forum to ask this question please let me know where and I will move it.

This question in salesforce formus:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gPfwAAE

Describes perfectly my question but never got answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to this, the developers just need to pay attention when creating fields

Comment: That's the answer I figured I was going to get.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah and it's one of those things they will have no interest in changing also, it's one of things

Comment: Honestly it was worth an ask but I'm sure you are correct in saying it will stay this way.